# Cannot load library qtquickcontrols2plugin.dll

Tags: qt, deployment, qml

I am upgrading Qt in my solution from Qt5 to Qt6 (6.3). When running a qml based project I receive the error that qtquickcontrols2plugin.dll cannot be loaded - a specified module is missing. I have checked with dependency walker and the .dll needs the Qt6Qml.dll, Qt6Core.dll, Qt6QuickControls2.dll which are all near the executable file in the deployment directory.

The plugin dll is under the directory folder_with_executable\QtQuick\Controls. The qmldir file looks as follows:

```
module QtQuick.Controls
linktarget Qt6::qtquickcontrols2plugin
plugin qtquickcontrols2plugin
classname QtQuickControls2Plugin
designersupported
typeinfo plugins.qmltypes
import QtQuick.Controls.impl auto
optional import QtQuick.Controls.Basic auto
optional import QtQuick.Controls.Fusion auto
optional import QtQuick.Controls.Material auto
optional import QtQuick.Controls.Imagine auto
optional import QtQuick.Controls.Universal auto
optional import QtQuick.Controls.Windows auto
optional import QtQuick.Controls.macOS auto
prefer :/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls/
```

Can anyone please help ? Is the folder directory for qml correct ?
I am deploying for windows on windows 10 with the precompiled mingw Qt dlls.

Comment: From the backslashes in your question, it appears you are running on Windows? How are you deploying your package? Have you used `windeployqt`?

Comment: No. I have not use until now, but now I let it run and it added more dlls near my executable such that my project executable runs now. Thank you for the useful tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your answer is solved with `windeployqt`. That is the recommended way to package your application on Windows since you never know when newer dependencies may creep in but you can rely on the fact that Qt will keep that tool up to date.

Answer (score 1):

How I actually solved this without having to use windeployqt: After I have successfully configured the system on Windows with the above solution I went to do the same for Linux. But there is no windeployqt for Linux. After searching for a while I found the solution to debugging the problem: set the environment variable QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS and run the program. This showed what library was actually missing. After adding all the required libraries to the CMakeLists.txt I took the configuration for Linux, and made sure that the installation worked for Linux, and I adapted the INSTALL cmake commands to the Windows dlls. It worked. I was able to successfully install on Windows as well without using windeployqt.